Как одновременно запустить телеграмм и вк ботов
У меня есть два бота - тг и вк, как мне их запустить вместе, чтобы они работали одновременно
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

# Инициализация бота
bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

# Обработчик команды /start бота
@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    ...
        

@dp.message()
async def bot_message(msg: types.Message):
    ...

for event in longpoll.listen():
    print(longpoll.listen())
    asyncio.create_task(main())
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            ...

async def main() -> None:
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Сейчас при запуске работает только вк бот, но нужно, чтобы и работал тг бот
Кто знает как решить, помогите, буду очень благодарен
